# How does the Presenter know which Model is manipulated through it's showing View?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I have started to study **MVP** on Android framework since I would like to start my future works in some design patters and I read that MVP is more than appropriate for building Android apps.

I have a question about an **MVP** principle:

The example is:

I have a **View** that have **2 interaction** options:

- first is listing items on the screen, for example: fruits.
- second is when the fruits are listed user can click to it and it should print out the number of letters in the word

The **Presenter** should catch the event when a **fruit is clicked**, count the letters, and call the View's print function.

With MVP I tried this with this approach:

**My View:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainView, View.OnClickListener {

ViewGroup fruitsContainer;
Button    listFruitsBtn;

MyPresenter myPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Making my presenter, its only parameter is a MainView, this MainView.
    myPresenter = new MyPresenter(this);

    fruitsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fruitsContainer);
    listFruitsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_fruits_btn);
    listFruitsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

/**
 * Showing fruits, making a TextView for each.
 */
@Override
public void showFruits(List<String> fruits) {

    fruitsContainer.removeAllViews();

    for (String fruit : fruits) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fruit);

        //Question part 1: How does the presenter will know WHICH fruit is clicked?
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);

        fruitsContainer.addView(textView);
    }
}

/**
 * When user clicks on the "show fruits" button, the view calls for presenter to take action.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.equals(listFruitsBtn)) {
        myPresenter.fruitButtonClicked();
    }
    else if(v instanceof TextView)
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v;
        //Question part 2: How does the presenter will know WHICH fruit is clicked?
        //In theory this operation is forbidden as far as I know.
        //MVP does not supports views to know anything about the Model that they are showing.
        myPresenter.fruitIsClicked(textView.getText().toString());
    }

    }
}
```

**My Presenter:**

```
public class MyPresenter {

MainView mainView;

public MyPresenter(MainView mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;
}

/**
 * Got a callback for "show fruits" event invoked
 * so we call the mainView's showFruits function with the model's data parameter
 */
public void fruitButtonClicked() {
    this.mainView.showFruits(MyModel.getFruitsList());
}

//In theory this operation is forbidden as far as I know.
//MVP does not supports views to know anything about the Model that they are showing.
public void fruitIsClicked(String fruit) {

    //Clicked operation - counting letters - call print operation of myView



   }
}
```

**Attention**: The **Model** being a *String* here is only because for simplifying the example, it could be any robust class.

As I understood one of the MVP's principle that **Views does not know anything about the Model** they are showing. So one does not okay to save the Model instance as an attribute of the View instance, and later on when needed (when the interaction made) passing the Model instance to Presenter to do further business logic. (counting letters)

So my question is in situations like this, when **Views are represents a particular Model instance**, how does the presenter knows exactly which one of the Model instance is being in interaction?

If i misunderstood something please care to elaborate an explanation to me.

(I have learnt from [this site](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby));

Answer (score 0):

You would have your view inform the presenter which position in the list was selected, then the presenter would select the correct fruit from the model, and then set the appropriate views in the view.  Here is a quick contrived example. (in pretty much pseudo-code)

Lets say you have a view that has a ListView (mList) for displaying a list of fruits,  an ImageView (mImage)  to show a nice picture of the selected fruit, and a TextView (mText) to show a description of the selected Fruit.

You would set an on item listener for the mList to report when a item is selected,  so something like this in your view class:

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mPresenter.onItemSelected(position);

    }

    });

public void setText(String text) {
    mText.text = text;
}

public void setImage(...) {
}
```

Then in your presenter class, you would have a onItemSelected method that gathered the required values from your model (the fruit list) and set the widgets in the view

```
public void onItemSelected(int position) {
   Fruit fruit = model.getFruitAt(position);
   view.setText(fruit.getText());
   view.setImage(fruit.getImage();
}
```

Update:
Another way would be to have the presenter implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface and just assign the presenter in the view.

So In the view just have this.

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(mPresenter);
```

Then in the presenter add the implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener to the class definition and implement the listener there.
The downside with this is that the presenter would know about the android View class,  I think it would be better if the view and presenter communicated via a platform independent interface, so probably just sending the position might be best.

Comment: So Views can send back positions to Presenter. Is it the appropriate way used by MVP? Or is it just a workaround? I have not found any online sources about this approach that is why I posted a question about it, can you link some sources maybe?

Comment: I a view has to report something,  I am not sure you will find anything that covers that level of detail.   A listview is a widget that displays a list and can report which item in the list was selected,  it does not know what the item that was selected was, just that some item was selected.  If you wanted to be even more "pure",  you could have the presenter implement the onItemClickListener, and then in the view simply set the presenter as the onItemClickListener.